# How to apply Shadow theme for rendering calendar within its own shadow DOM (added in v6.1.0)

Tags: javascript, dom, calendar, fullcalendar, shadow

I recently used the `FullCalendar` with the `WebComponent` and I'm trying to use the Shadow Theme but I can't find the way to do it in the documentation with JavaScript. To add more context, the Shadow DOM appears [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/web-component).

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

var calendar;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    aspectRatio: 3,
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
    },
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: As far as I can see you have to do it by writing `<full-calendar shadow` ... in the HTML. Maybe raise a ticket with the fullCalendar maintainers on their Github, if you think the documentation is inadequate.